# Get the Id of parent DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a table inside div.

```
<div id="aaa">
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <button></button>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can i get the Id of div which is "aaa" from button? I tried to use closest and parent but it gives me 'undefined' output.

```
$(this).closest('div').attr('id');
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me.  Is the button `this`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one. Here you go. Keep coding !

```js
function findID(){
  var id = $("button").closest("div").prop("id");
  $("#display").text(id);
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: black;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}

#display {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="aaa">
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <button onclick="findID()">Find ID</button>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```